# Jquery datebox calendar week start day

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying out Jquery Mobile DateBox.

See here: [mobile date box](http://dev.jtsage.com/)

In the calendar I need to week to start on Monday instead of Sundays.

How can I set this please?

Comment: Looking at the API, it doesn't seem to be something the author allowed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code the following array keeps the days of the week:

```
daysOfWeek: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
```

Perhaps if you change the order here with a bit of tweaking (if necessary) you can change the order as you need.

Comment: Since this is in the internationalization category, I doubt this would do anything but but mis-label the days.  But yes, tweaking the source code may be required since it doesn't seem to be allowed for.

Comment: Yeah, tried changing the order in the array but the dates are not right anymore :o/

Comment: Yes, you need to delve more into it. But its a start. make it go wrong and fix it with the new array

Answer (score 2):

Use "overrideCalStartDay" with value "1" in the "data-options" of calendars input. It works for me.

```
<input ... data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "overrideCalStartDay": 1}' ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a bit after the fact, but I have gotten around to adding this option.  As it happens, a few years back, a colleague of mine started our work calendars on Monday, and I have hated it ever since.  However, it was requested a few places, and it now exists.

```
<input ... data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "calStartDay": 1}' ... />
```

Where *calStartDay* is in the standard form of 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ... 6=Saturday.

Comment: After a quick search for this, I have found one little problem when you change to start day of the week, the week no. doesn't tally up any more. So while the date/days are correct, Monday still falls on the week before in terms of its week no. which makes processing things a little more difficult.